# Cannot route to other pages in SPA angular with dynamic list

Tags: javascript, angularjs, router

I'm using single page application using angular 1.6. Whenever I use the static list to redirect the routes, it was working fine, but when trying with dynamic list from json, i couldn't get it.

Here is the JSON:

```
 {
      "People": [{
          "name": "Andrew Amernante",
          "rating": 3,
        },
        {
          "name": "Frank Wang",
          "rating": 5,
        },
        {
          "name": "Chang Wang",
          "rating": 5,
        }
      ]
    }
```

In Controller, I have these code snippets.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(['$locationProvider', function($locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.hashPrefix('');
  }]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider

  .when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'Andrew Amernante.html',
    controller  : 'HomeController'
  })

  .when('/blog', {
    templateUrl : 'Frank Wang.html',
    controller  : 'BlogController'
  })

  .when('/about', {
    templateUrl : 'Sissi Chen.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })

  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('people.json').
  then(function onSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.peoples = response.data;

  }).
  catch(function onError(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

And, I wanted to iterate the array and display the three name in list.

```
<ul class="nav">
      <li class="active" ng-repeat="item in peoples.People track by $index">
                    <a href="#{{item.name}}">{{item.name}}</a>
       </li>
 </ul>

<div ng-view></div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="Andrew Amernante.html">
    <h1>Home</h1>
    <h3>{{message}}</h3>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="Frank Wang.html">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <h3>{{message}}</h3>
  </script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="Sissi Chen.html">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <h3>{{message}}</h3>
  </script>
```

Here is the plunkr code - [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/iheQU9mYXZwyHVlI6MeP?p=preview)

Comment: expectation is whenever we route the pages from anchor tag, it should display the template messages, pls see the plnkr code to get better idea

Comment: Can you give an example of the working static list? Do you have a plunkr for that? I think you are misunderstanding how routing works, but you say you have a working version

Comment: here is the example for static list. http://next.plnkr.co/edit/ClBmOH3ljAWueRBdKGKR?preview

Comment: Your problem is that you're routing to `/blog`, `/about`, so when you redirect to `Frank Wang` for example, this route doesn't  exist. Also, I suggest you to change the approach once you're trying to have blank spaces in your URL.

Comment: blog, about is is for static list, Here, I'm using dynamic list from json. both are different

Comment: What I'm trying to explain you is that you don't have any route to handle what you're expecting, take a look at your own plunker with a few changes: http://plnkr.co/edit/4N45j4vzTTdIiNlmD8bH?p=preview

Comment: I can't tell if you're using AngularJS or Angular, and you've used both tags. Please [edit] your question to remove the tag that does not apply.

Comment: @LuizCarlos: In your plnkr code, I'm seeing the same home controller is called for all the routings

Comment: Yes, @UI_Dev, the idea here is to handle the `$routeParams` to achieve what you expect. The way you're trying to do is not feasible in angularjs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding how routing works in AngularJS:

Any one route can only have a single template and controller. There is a 1 to 1 relationship between a route and a template.

Routes must be accessed buy a fully qualified URL (it's got to have a slash in there somewhere). **A hash tag followed by the `id` attribute of the template tag as your `href` is not how you access a route**.

**Additionally, route definitions in AngularJS cannot be defined dynamically.** So, you really should consider using one single route to display the data of each of your dynamically loaded objects. You can use route parameters to pass the object. For example:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="person.html">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <h3>{{message}}</h3>
</script>
```

Then your route will define that it can accept a route parameter like this:

```
.when('/people/:person', {
  templateUrl : 'person.html',
  controller  : 'PersonController'
 });
```

Your navigation will change:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="active" ng-repeat="item in peoples.People track by $index">
     <a href="/people/{{item.uniqueId}}">{{item.name}}</a>
   </li>
 </ul>
```

This also requires you to change your data. You must have some unique identifier with no spaces to use the route params:

```
 {
  "People": [{
      "name": "Andrew Amernante",
      "rating": 3,
      "uniqueId": "andrew-amernante"
    },
    {
      "name": "Frank Wang",
      "uniqueId": "frank-wang",
      "rating": 5,
    },
    {
      "name": "Chang Wang",
      "uniqueId": "chang-wang",
      "rating": 5,
    }
  ]
}
```

You would then have to search your data in a PersonController to find the item with the same uniqueId

```
app.controller('PersonController', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
  $http.get('people.json').
  then(function onSuccess(response) {
    console.log(response);
    $scope.person = response.data.find(function(item) {
      return item.uniqueId == $routeParams.person;
    });
    $scope.message = person.name;
    $scope.title = "Home"; // or "About" or "Blog";
  }).
  catch(function onError(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

*Read completely (this shows a quick fix which is not recommended in "real life" apps!)*

---

The **error** lies in how you're mapping your routes.

Especifically there is an inconsistency between the `when` and the content which carries the `name` property of the objects in `people.json#People`.

For instance the below code expects routes for `blog` and `about`

```
  .when('/blog', { // < -- there is no route for this!
    templateUrl : 'Frank Wang.html',
    controller  : 'BlogController'
  })

  .when('/about', { // < -- there is no route for this!
    templateUrl : 'Sissi Chen.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })
```

But you provide (by doing `href="#{{item.name}}"`) these routes: `Andrew Amernante`, `Frank Wang`, `Chang Wang`, and so on... so... the names in the objects contained in `People` array.

In order to (quickly) **fix this** change the previous code to:

```
  .when('/Andrew Amernante', {
    templateUrl : 'Frank Wang.html',
    controller  : 'BlogController'
  })

  .when('/Frank Wang', {
    templateUrl : 'Sissi Chen.html',
    controller  : 'AboutController'
  })
  // add one for every name
  .when('/<every-name>', {
    templateUrl : '<every-name>.html',
    controller  : '<every-controller>'
  })
```

See this alternative in [**this forked Plunker**](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/iuRUafXU8QE3ach0?preview).

**But** in "real" apps **this is not a maintainable code**.

Instead you should do as suggested in [this answer by Pop-A-Stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51270206/cannot-route-to-other-pages-in-spa-angular-with-dynamic-list/51271083#51271083) in which you provide a template and the content changes according to a provided parameter.

Answer (score -1):

Whenever we are required to route to certain page by $locationProvider , we have to give the exact address what we configure in the config section.

You are referring to `item.name` in the json which doesn't match with any of the above configured location mapped with any templates.

As per your problem it depends on your need what exactly you want to modify. If modification in json and html works for you you can go with below approach.

For dynamic loading you can have an extra variable `address` in the json as a field pointing to blog , about etc.

and in your html you can give it as `href="#{{item.address}}"`.

or

if you dont want to modify the json or html then simply you can change the config to:

```
.when('/Andrew Amernante', {
templateUrl : 'Andrew Amernante.html',
controller  : 'HomeController'
})
.when('/Frank Wang', {
templateUrl : 'Frank Wang.html',
controller  : 'BlogController'
})
.when('/Sissi Chen', {
templateUrl : 'Sissi Chen.html',
controller  : 'AboutController'
})
.otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

Hope it will work!!